# asp.net iis server red asterisk page validation

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net

I'm getting a strange error with my ASP.NET website.

I'm developping with C#, Asp.Net and Visual Studio. When developping and starting my website with Visual Studio (Ctrl+F5), VS starts its own web server and everything is fine.

Now I'm deploying a web server on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server. I've installed my IIS Server, copied my website and the website is starting properly !

My problem : When trying to log on my website, all my required fields get a red asterisk beside them even tho I enter correct values in them !

Must be some kind of configuration problem on this server but I can't manage to find where to look for !

The ASPX Login code :

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" onloggedin="Login1_LoggedIn" OnLoginError="Login1_LoginError">
<fieldset>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" defaultbutton="LoginButton">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td align="left">
<globalization:TranslatedLabel runat="server" Text="UserName" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="Wxpt" DicoEnum="USERNAME" DicoScope="HOME" ID="lblUserName" />
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>                                             
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Width="183px" skin="Wxpt" 
EnableEmbeddedSkins="False">
</telerik:RadTextBox>

</td>
<td>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="padding-top:10px;">
<globalization:TranslatedLabel runat="server" Text="    EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="Wxpt" DicoEnum="PASSWORD" DicoScope="HOME"
ID="lblPassword" />
</td>
<td>
</td>
<tr>
<td>
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="Password" runat="server" Width="183px" 
TextMode="Password"    EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" Skin="Wxpt" AutoPostBack="False">
</telerik:RadTextBox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="1" style="color: Red;">
<asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" colspan="1" style="padding-top:10px;">
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Login" 
ValidationGroup="Login1" UseSubmitBehavior="True" ></asp:Button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
</fieldset>
</LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your login aspx page? Are you using forms authentication?

Comment: Yes, I'm using forms authentication... I don't think the problem comes from the ASPX code, because it's working like a charm when using VS's web server !